# SCP command altering filesize of tranferred data

Tags: linux, scp, rhel, data-transfer

**Context:**
I am transferring a backup dir from Server A to Server B.(RHEL)
Directory size (to be transferred) on Server A: *48GB*
Available space on Server B: *154GB*

---

**Command I'm using on Server A(user: root):**

```
scp -r -C <nameof-backup-dir> user@severB:/path
```

---

**Unexpected Behaviour:**
The backup directory appears on the target server B @/path occupying all available 154GB of space.
Meanwhile the SCP run on the source server A terminates with an "Insufficent space message" for the remaining files.

---

**Question/Help needed:**

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. What changes do I need to make to the SCP command to achieve the result?

Comment: How have you measured "directory size"?

Comment: @KamilCuk I used `du -shc ./*` on the parent directory of the backup-dir to get it's size.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su]. When you do, it'd be helpful to mention what kind of files these are, in other words what programs use them and what kind of data is in them.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is that block sizes are different.

If block size on the destination machine is bigger, small files will occupy more space.

To find out block size :

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep -i 'block size'
# Replace /dev/sda1 with your device (found out with command [df])
```

If it's indeed the case, you can recreate destination file system with the same block size as the source file system.